# Jenkins Build of SoapUI test - No testsuite found

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

I am trying to build a SoapUI testSuite through maven on Jenkins.  Using maven, I was able to successfully build the testSuite on my local machine and all the test cases executed too.  But on Jenkins, it doesn't seem to find any Test Suite to run! This is rather confusing for me, as this is my first foray into SoapUI, Maven as well as Jenkins.

The console output from Jenkins is:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ WAR_DDCService ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DDCAutomationSuite/workspace/src/test/resources
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ WAR_DDCService ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WAR_DDCService ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ WAR_DDCService ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DDCAutomationSuite/workspace/target/surefire-reports
```

On viewing the output, what is confusing me is that it seems to look for the test Suite in "resources" folder.  Whereas, the soapui testsuite is located within the src/tests/soapui folder.

Below is the section from the pom.xml file for this Project where I have mentioned the path too.  Can someone help me in understanding where I am going wrong?

I have specified the following location of the project File also in the pom.xml in the configuration.

```
Hi Samuel, thank you for the response. Please find the pom.xml content below:

<plugin>
<groupId>eviware</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.5.1</version>                
<configuration>
<projectFile>src/test/soapui/DaonDerivedCredential-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
<outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
<junitReport>true</junitReport>
<printReport>true</printReport>
<projectProperties>
<projectProperty>endpoint=<a href="http://foo.com/foo-0.2.1-SNAPSHOT/services/ddc</a></projectProperty>
</projectProperties>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run the build from my local setup through the command prompt I give the command "mvn eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:test" which executes the SoapUI TestSuite located in the /src/test/soapui folder. On Jenkins.. I am not aware of where this command will have to be entered for Jenkins to execute it.

Comment: Hard to know what is wrong, we need some more information. Could you post a bit more of your pom, and the maven command you try to run ? It is not clear for me if you expect something from the soapui plugin or from the resources plugin

Comment: Hi Samuel.. I've updated the contents of the original post in response to your clarifications. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Try to prefix with ${basedir}

<projectFile>${basedir}src/test/soapui/DaonDerivedCredential-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>

Comment: Ah ok I see. You have to tell jenkins that you want to run mvn eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:test in order to have it performed, as this goal is not in the default lifecycle

Comment: To do so, you have a "Goals and options" form input, in the config file of your project in Jenkins (probably near the bottom of the page). Of course, your project should have been created in Jenkins as a Maven project.

Comment: yes... I see it. And there I had entered "clean test".  Should I be entering the command "mvn eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:test" in the "Goals and options" form?

Comment: Yes, and more, depending on what you want to perform.

Comment: I 've sum it up in an answer, with a link to a page explaining the basics of maven lifecycle.

Comment: Hi Samuel.. I added the command into the goal but it failed still however the error this time seems different.

Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources,..

Comment: Hi, sorry for the mistake, you should not put "mvn" in the command line, but only the arguments. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go in "Goals and options" form input, in the config file of your project in Jenkins (probably near the bottom of the page).

You can set it to

> clean eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:test

in order to have jenkins performing your tests.

As by default this goal is bound to the integration-test phase, it should go throught the default lifecycle and finish by performing your tests.

For more info, see :

```
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html
```